# Which meaning of "impose" is "imposing" based on?

Tags: meaning

Which meaning of "impose" is "imposing" based on? From Wikionary,

"imposing" means "Magnificent and impressive because of appearance, size, stateliness or dignity."

"impose" means

> (transitive) To establish or apply by authority.
>
> (intransitive) to be an inconvenience
>
> to enforce: compel to behave in a certain way
>
> To practice a trick or deception.
>
> To lay on, as the hands, in the religious rites of confirmation and ordination.
>
> To arrange in proper order on a table of stone or metal and lock up in a chase for printing; said of columns or pages of type, forms,
>   etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in between the first one and the third one, *to make a great impression, to be heavy upon one's mind*. When something is imposing, it overwhelms you with its force or skill, it is formidable. Latin *impono* means "to put (something) in/onto (something)". So an imposing statue affects you by the metaphoric weight of its splendour or size. A similar metaphor lies behind *impressive*.